# Stitching together of arrays in python/numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

If I were to define an array as generated text imported from a .csv file, e.g.:

```
x, y, z, a = np.genfromtxt('/Users/iMacHome/Downloads/array.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```

Which say has the same number of row elements as another array which is also generated as text from an imported .csv file, e.g.,:

```
b, c, d, e = np.genfromtxt('/Users/iMacHome/Downloads/anotherarray.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```

Am I able to stitch them as one array, producing:

```
yetanotherarray = [x, y, z, a, b, c, d, e]
```

I'm not sure on the exact way to go about doing this within python. Does anyone have any pointers at all? Do I need the help of numpy arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
np.hstack((x, y, z, a, b, c, d, e))
```

Comment: or `np.vstack`, `np.dstack` `np.r_`, `np.c_`, `np.concatenate` depending on the desired shapes.

Comment: @ev-br Was just about to update with that :-) (well `vstack` and `dstack` anyway).

Comment: Each row represents a different physical object's properties, so I would say hstack is what I need for my specific example, but thank you for including the different ways to 'stack' the array for others to use. Will accept the answer as soon as I can. Many thanks

Comment: @atomh33ls based on some cases I've had, using `np.concatenate()` can be considerably faster for 1-D arrays...